# Use command prompt to alter the local group Administrator policy for a machine remotely

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I've been trying to get the `net localgroup` command to work, but I'm not sure if it's possible to use it for another separate computer on the domain. I am attempting to add an existing group to the policy remotely, not just a user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pstools to do the needful. For example I add the command to add the domain user to the local admin group remotely.

```
psexec \\remotename -u username -p pwd net localgroup Administrators "domain\user" /add
```

Comment: That's the solution I've found, however I wasn't clear in my posting that I am looking to add a group of users to the policy, not just a user. Thanks for the hasty reply though!

Comment: @Batman666 Just substitute the "domain\user" with "domain\group" instead.